# How do I force implementations of a method to be inside a try-catch block in Java?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This may be a Java question, or it may be an Eclipse question, I'm not positive.

I'm creating custom View in Android: `HelpTextView extends View`

I would like to override `View.setVisibility()`, forcing calls to `HelpTextView.setVisibility()` to be written inside `try-catch (NullPointerException nex)` blocks.

I added both a throws declaration to the method  (which is what I thought would do the trick) as well as a throw command but no luck.  Is this not working because it's simply never going to work (perhaps overriding just doesn't work that way) or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this because NullPointerException is a RuntimeException, which does not need to be caught by the caller.

Your best approach is to implement your own Exception.

```
public class HelpTextView extends View {

    public setThisVisibility(boolean isVisible) throws MyNullPointerException {
        ...
    }
```

}

and your `MyNullPointerException` cannot be RuntimeException

Answer (score 3):

`NullPointerException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`. A `RuntimeException` is an [unchecked exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), meaning that you do not need to catch it.

No matter how you declare your method, you cannot force a NullPointerException to be caught.

You can, however, create your own `Exception` and force that to be caught.

Comment: Really? The Java documentation that I linked to begs to differ.

Comment: what you said is correct.

Comment: Tanis.7x is indeed correct.

Comment: Heh, the guy who said you were incorrect deleted his comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can not override a method and add an exception which is not already declared in super method except RuntimeExceptions.